# how to build a mail server in java

Tags: jakarta-mail

greetings all
i have an app(spring+hibernate) that needs to send thousands of emails simultaneously 
and i was told that the best solution here is to have a mail server
i don't have any idea where to start or if there's a framework or a service that is better
so please guys give me some info where to start, thank you.

Comment: It sounds like you were told to *use* a mail server, not *write* one. In which case, @Jeff's answer is correct. If you are infact trying to write your own mail server, might we first ask why? And then, more specifically, where are you getting stuck?

Comment: oops sorry guys, yes use using a mail server, and i want to use the best one that enables me to send,receive many emails simultaneously and filter the received emails, please guide me

Answer (score 3):

You don't build a mail server.  You use the JavaMail API to access a mail server (SMTP server) in order to send emails.  [Here is an explanation of the JavaMail API](http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/JavaMail/contents.html).

Answer (score 0):

Use Java mail api to send mail that you can do through ultimately you need an SMTP server to deliver the mail, and if you want it local you can use iis SMTP mail, hmail server or other available SMTP servers, and need to configure it correctly to send lots of mail.

check out for sending mail using Java

http://www.javacommerce.com/displaypage.jsp?name=javamail.sql&id=18274

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_sending_email.htm

http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=144